# Error #1009 flash, can't figure it out

Tags: actionscript-3, error-handling

I'm busy programming a game, but I've run stuck on something.

I've been able to let the game work perfectly before, but all of the sudden it stopped working.

Here is the part of the script that is giving the error:

```
var colorTransform:ColorTransform;
        var player:MovieClip;
        var kaas:MovieClip;
        var ground:MovieClip;
        var speed:Number;
        var right:Boolean = false;
        var left:Boolean = false;
        var up:Boolean = false;
        var down:Boolean = false;
        var isWalking:Boolean = false;
        var isJumping:Boolean = false;
        var jumpSpeedLimit:int = 14;
        var jumpSpeed:Number = jumpSpeedLimit;
        // END

        public function main() 
        {
            speed = 5;
            kaas = new Kaas();
            kaas.y = 300;
            kaas.x = 300;
            addChild(kaas);
            ground = new Ground();
            ground.y = stage.stageHeight;
            ground.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
            addChild(ground);
            player = new Player();
            player.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - player.width;
            player.y = stage.stageHeight - 45;
            player.width = 50;
            player.height = 50;
            addChild(player);
            player.gotoAndStop("idle");
            //event listeners.
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyupCheck);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keydownCheck);
            player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movePlayer);
        }
```

I hope someone could help me out.

this is the error message I get:

```
typeerror error #1009 cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.at main()
```

Thanks in advance,
Remy

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact error message?

Comment: oh I'm sorry, I updated it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means you are trying to access a property, but that object has not been instantiented/does not exist/is currently null.

I'm not 100% sure which of the classes you use in main() might not be ready, but a very common one is the stage, which is a null object the display object has been added to the stage.
In this case try something like this in the last part of main():

```
 //event listeners.
this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,stageReady);
}
private function stageReady(event:Event):void{
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyupCheck);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keydownCheck);
            player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movePlayer);
}
```

Comment: Well this doesn't quite help, I keep getting the error.
Even if I make all lines a commentary line except one child (ground for example) it also gives me this error while it worked perfectly before

Comment: and I'm pretty sure it's not the stage that is the problem

Comment: hmm after a few tests I discovered that the problem was setting the player.x & player.y to the stagewidth which appearently wasn't ready yet all of the sudden.
Thanks alot :)

Comment: it was the stage after all :) I missed the stage references above the event listeners setup